# Implementing and using IDisposable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with a 3rd party object that implements IDisposable. In order to make it unit test "able" I build a wrapper. I understand that object implements IDisposable my wrapper needs to implement IDisposable as well.

```
public interface IWrapper : IDisposable
{
    void Complete();
}

public class Wrapper : IWrapper
{
    private readonly ThirdPartyLib lib;

    public Wrapper()
    {
        lib = new ThirdPartyLib();
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        lib.Comlete();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lib.Dispose();
    }
}

public class Processor : IProcessor
{
    private readonly IWrapper wrapper;
    public Processor(IWrapper wrapper)
    {
        this.wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void Process()
    {
        // do some work
        using (wrapper) {
            // do more work
        }
    }
}
```

Suppose Processor is injected in some class that is using it and Process() is executed

- What happends to wrapper if we call Process() again? - wouldn't ThirdPartyLib() throw an exception since it was created only once (in wrappers constructor) and now it has been disposed
- Does it not get disposed as long as there is a reference to it?
- Should the wrapper maybe be build in such a way that new() "ing" of ThirdPartyLib be performed not in a constructor but in a seperate method, say Begin() - like so:

> ```
> public class Wrapper : IWrapper
>     {
>       private ThirdPartyLib lib;
>
>       public void Begin()
>       {
>           lib = new ThirdPartyLib();
>       }
>
>       public void Complete()
>       {
>           lib.Comlete();
>       }
>
>       public void Dispose()
>       {
>           lib.Dispose();
>       }
>     }
> ```

Then using it:

```
using (wrapper.Begin()) {
```

Comment: I feel that we don't have the big picture for this. Why would the `Processor` only ever process one `Wrapper` that was injected into the constructor? Usually I'd expect that you're `Processor` would have a method call like `Process(IWrapper wrapper)` allowing you to process that wrapper, but again I'd be in the camp that it would be the callers imperative to call 'Dispose' on the `IWrapper` since it effectively owns it. If this isn't the case then I'd likely implement `IDisposable` on the `IProcessor` and only dispose of the `IWrapper` when that disposes.

Comment: Would implementing IDisposable on IProcessor only dispose Wrapper when IProcessor is disposed (in the current design), and not when "}" of using statement is hit? Is this because (parent) IProcessor holds a reference to IWrapper - even tho we told it to be disposed on "}"

Comment: That's why objects initialised with DI should assume _they own the injected object_.   Most of the time they are singletons used by other objects or at least something else is controlling the lifetime.  DI-dependent objects should merely _use_ the object and assume that.whatever created the incoming object, is also responsible for nuking it later.  DI is like _"hey I just want an object, someone else can create and delete it for me"_

Comment: "Does it not get disposed as long as there is a reference to it?" -- I think that once there are no longer any strong references to an object, then it is available for garbage collection. GC calls an object's *finalizer*, GC does not look for Dispose() and call it. An object being garbage collected due to no more references has ~nothing to do with that object's Dispose() method; they are only related when a finalizer is implemented for an object that explicitly calls Dispose. In your code the object is only "disposed" when *you* call Dispose, which are you are doing in the `using` statement.

Comment: _"Does it not get disposed as long as there is a reference to it?"_ - well if you call `Dispose()` then the offending object _will_ get nuked regardless of reference count.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be concerned. Calling `Process()` twice would likely cause an exception. Not calling `Process()` at all would leave the object undisposed.

There is no simple rule for what you should do instead. There are multiple options, and which can be used depends on other parts of your code that aren't in your question.

If `Processor` takes a reference to an externally owned `Wrapper`, then it should not dispose that wrapper at all.

If `Processor` takes ownership of the `Wrapper` at construction time, then it should dispose that wrapper at dispose time. This means `Processor` should implement `IDisposable` as well.

If `Processor` can be modified to create a new `Wrapper` on demand, then that wrapper can be disposed when `Process()` is done with it.

Or, as you suggested, if `Wrapper` can be modified to create a `ThirdPartyLib` on demand, that could work too. But be careful: calling `wrapper.Begin(); wrapper.Begin();` would leave one `ThirdPartyLib` undisposed and unreferenced. You'd need to restructure your API a bit more to prevent this from becoming a problem, and effectively, that would mean turning your `Wrapper` into a `ThirdPartyLibFactory`.

Comment: can you please explain how calling: wrapper.Begin(); wrapper.Begin(); would leave one undisposed?

Comment: @BobSwanson `wrapper.Begin()` creates third party lib, let's call it A. Then you call it again, now you have a second third party lib created, let's call it B. Now your private variable `lib` points to B, and nothing points to A any more. When you call `wrapper.End()` it calls `lib.Dispose()` which disposes B, but A is still around and cannot be disposed any more as you lost the only reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Processor` should not dispose of `IWrapper`, because it is not the one that instantiated it and it doesn't know if it can be disposed or if it's being injected into other objects.  In that case, `Processor` should not use `using` with wrapper.

The code to dispose of `IWrapper` should be in the class that instantiated it in the first place, since that's the one that knows about it's lifecycle.